# Exclude specific type of files from being commited to github

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and so far I did not find a simple method of doing this.

I am trying to upload a folder to my remote repository but I don't want certain type of files to be uploaded. I need some guidance in terms of syntax and such to prevent those type of files from uploading.

Comment: The answer you linked was not really helpful but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify your file name in the `.gitignore` file.

Read about it in the following link:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files